# why does the position of "int i;" matters in this case?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm teaching myself C since my uni seems to be obsessed with java, so im writing a stack implementation of type int (ill worry about making it generic later). I came across an error that makes not sense to me, `missing ';' before 'type'`. As far as i can tell my syntax is right, if it is not please do tell. Anyways here is my code:

stack.h

```
typedef struct{
    int *elements;
    int size;
    int capacity;
}Stack;

void newStack(Stack *s);
void delStack(Stack *s);
void pushToStack(Stack *s, int value);
int popFromStack(Stack *s);
```

stack.c

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void newStack(Stack *s){
    s->size = 0;
    s->capacity = 4;
    s->elements = (int*) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

    assert(s->elements != NULL); // allocation worked?
}

void delStack(Stack *s){
    free(s->elements);
}

void pushToStack(Stack *s, int value){
    if(s->size == s->capacity){
        s->size *= 2;
        s->elements = (int *) realloc(s->elements, s->size * sizeof(int));

        assert(s->elements !=NULL); //reallocation worked?
    }
    s->elements[s->size] = value;
    s->size++;
}

int popFromStack(Stack *s){
    assert(s->size>0);
    s->size --;
    return s->elements[s->size];
}

int main()
{
    Stack s1;
    newStack(&s1);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        pushToStack(&s1, i);
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
        printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%d ", popFromStack(&s1));
    }

    delStack(&s1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs in main, on the `int i;` line, but if i move the line up the error goes away and the program runs flawlessly. I want to know why.

CAUSES ERROR:

```
    newStack(&s1);
    int i;
```

NO ERROR:

```
    int i;
    newStack(&s1);
```

PS: just in case it matters.. im using MS Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @delman - I realised that just after I pressed the post button. Been a long day and you cannot delete comments.

Comment: @EdHeal I for one can delete my comments (observe!) -- X in a circle, right next to the time, only shows when hovering over the comment.

Comment: @delnam - I Keep forgetting that it only appears on hover (does not help that I am colour blind)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio is stuck in a time loop somewhere before 1998, back when the standard mandated that all declarations should be at the beginning of a block.

This was changed in C99, and MS does say it supports the most popular features. Sadly this is not one of them.

Comment: The standard was that way through most of the nineties, so properly speaking what Visual Studio is stuck in is 1998 rather than 1989.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good call :-)

Comment: when i started i searched around for the consensus on what the best C compiler was for windows, and MS visual studio seem to always come up, so i went with that, is there a better choice? or should i just adjust my coding style?

Comment: @Lex Maybe they said it's the best IDE. Or maybe it's very good for C++. As far as C goes, you could try `gcc` or check the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers).

Answer (score 1):

In C you must declare all variables at the beginning of your scope. So you can't declare `i` after your `newStack` call.

Comment: @Justin But C up to and including C90 which is pretty much all half the C compilers out there care to implement.

Comment: The 1999 ISO C standard permits mixed declarations and statements within a block. Microsoft's C compiler doesn't support C99.

Comment: Yes. I realize I was making a statement that was a bit too generic, however, I also knew that it directly applied (and couldn't tell you when the standard allowed for the change)

Comment: @Justin I was speaking of full conformance. Yeah, if you just need this particular features (intermingled code and declarations), things look better, but still not perfect. Also, that table does not list the countless shitty compilers for various embedded platforms (had the pleasure to work with one once, it didn't even seem to support `if (some_int)`).

Answer (score 1):

In C89 declarations are made at the top of the scope and thus before any other function call.

However this restriction was removed in C99.

Comment: @Justin:- Ya I know, :) but still the date with C it mostly makes a sense of C89 and even ANSI C